# collection list and gridview

Tags: c#

I want to add `Mark1,Mark2,Mark3,Mark4,Mark5` and assign it to the `Sum` to show in the gridview.

i want to add those marks through any function and assign it to the Sum property. how to do it? thanks

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void procees()
    {            
        List<student> ml= new List<student>();

        student s1 = new student() {
            Name = "ram", 
            Id = "gn01", 
            Mark1 = 90, 
            Mark2 = 89,
            Mark3 = 75,
            Mark4 = 45,
            Mark5 = 65,
            Sum = "" 
        };
        ml.Add(s1);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = ml; 
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        procees();
    }
 }

 public class student
 {
     private string name;

     public string Name
     {
         get { return name; }
         set { name = value; }
     }

     private string id;

     public string Id
     {
         get { return id; }
         set { id = value; }
     }

     private int mark1;

     public int Mark1
     {
         get { return mark1; }
         set { mark1 = value; }
     }
     private int mark2;

     public int Mark2
     {
         get { return mark2; }
         set { mark2 = value; }
     }
     private int mark3;

     public int Mark3
     {
         get { return mark3; }
         set { mark3 = value; }
     }
     private int mark4;

     public int Mark4
     {
         get { return mark4; }
         set { mark4 = value; }
     }
     private int mark5;

     public int Mark5
     {
         get { return mark5; }
         set { mark5 = value; }
     }
     private int sum;

     public int Sum
     {
         get { return sum; }
         set { sum = value; }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Do you want to add marks in Gridview and then make total of it to show it in last column?

Comment: yes i want add the total and show it in last column.. vijay kumbhoje

Answer (score 1):

Remove private field 'sum':

```
 private int sum;
```

Let the pubic property 'Sum' to calculate the sum:

```
 public int Sum
 {
     get { return Mark1 + Mark2 + Mark3 + Mark4 + Mark5; }
 }
```